# Obtaining Metadata Information using ee_print function from RGEE

Tags: r, google-earth-engine, rgee

I am using the package `RGEE` (R wrapper for the Google Earth Engine Python API). The function `ee_print()` seems to work perfectly for an `ImageCollection` of just one variable, but seems to fail for `ImageCollection` with different variables where one needs to select the variable of interest. Any ideas on how to approach this issues with the latter kind of data.

Here's an example code:

```
GRIDMET = ee$ImageCollection("IDAHO_EPSCOR/GRIDMET")
ee_print(GRIDMET)
```

Where I get the following error message in return:

> Error in strsplit(code, ":") : non-character argument

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the following approach?

```
GRIDMET = ee$ImageCollection("IDAHO_EPSCOR/GRIDMET")
print(GRIDMET,  type = getOption("rgee.print.option"))
```

And play with the list of all metadata properties

```
GRIDMET$propertyNames()$getInfo()# Get a list of all metadata properties
(GRIDMET$get("product_tags")$getInfo()) # you can choose to show a characteristic like "product_tags"
```